# Print to screen after setting log file in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have set my output to be redirected to a log file as follows:
`exec &> $log_file`. I set this line at the very beginning of the script.

However, at the very end of the script I would like to print certain lines to the screen as well as that file; those lines are the results of the computations my script does.

Can any one guide me as to how to do that?

Comment: How about `tee -a` ? It will print on screen as well as write it in an output file too, try it out once.

Comment: you mean something like: `echo "results" | tee -a`? This does not work.

Comment: @DanAI: you want to display the content of the "$log_file" to the screen? and what are "print certain lines" of results of computations script? it's not clear...

Comment: No, I want the results to be printed to the screen as well as the log file and all other output to the log file only.

Comment: So basically there are only 2 lines that I want to be printed to both the log file and the screen and those 2 lines are printed at the very end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following. To remove effect of your `exec &> file` command you can use `exec &>/dev/tty` to bring writing back to standard output and standard errors. Then we could use `tee -a` command to write it on screen as well as on file.

```
cat my_script.sh
log_file="test_file"
exec &> $log_file
echo "12131313113...."
echo "test bla bla bla.."
exec &>/dev/tty
echo "test again...." | tee -a "$log_file"
```

Now when we run the script the last line should be printed on screen and should be saved into output file too.

```
./test.sh
test again....
##See the output of test file..
cat test_file
12131313113....
test bla bla bla..
test again....
```

Or alternatively:
`echo "output" > /dev/tty`

Comment: Or, as variation when appropriate, just use "echo blahblah > /dev/tty"?

Comment: @linuxfan, IMHO that is not writing into out file as per OP's need.

Comment: you are right, my comment was just for completeness about a wider problem.

Comment: @linuxfan, sure buddy, cheers.

Comment: This will log to the TTY, which may or may not be connected where the user expects. The proper solution is to save your original stdout and stderr when you `exec` so you can restore them when you need to.

Comment: @tripleee, Sure, thank you sir, will try to write a solution like that and edit post, thank you again sir.